# If both $R$ and $S$ are total order, will $T$ be total order?

Tags: examples-counterexamples, relations, self-learning, order-theory

Let $R$ be a total order on $A$ and let $S$ be total order on $B$.  Define $$T = \left\{\left(\left(a,b\right),\left(a',b'\right)\right) \in \left(A \times B\right) \times \left(A \times B\right) \;\vert\; aRa' \;\mathrm{and}\; bSb'\right\}$$
Is $T$ a total order on $A \times B$?

How do i find counter example of this?

Thanks

Comment: First, there's no $L$ in your example. Second, I don't think $(a,b),(a',b') \in A \times B \times A \times B$ is a legit definition (either $(a,b,a',b')$ or $((a,b),(a',b'))$

Comment: I would concur with Sudix's latter suggestion for notation. Also I do not understand what is being asked - $T$ can be made a reasonable definition by fixing its notation... and then? Show that $T$ is *not* in general a total order on $A \times B$?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $R=S=\{0, 1\}$ with $0 \leq 1$. Then in $R \times S$, $(0,1)$ and $(1, 0)$ are not comparable.

Comment: isnt that R HAS ordered pairs?

Comment: $R$ does and $S$ does too but $R \times S$ has unordered pairs. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: @FrejaJessen More generally, if $A$ and $B$ are both non-trivial (that is, $|A|>1$ and $|B|>1$), then $A \times B$ won't be a total ordered set.

Comment: @LukasKofler i am not sure i quite understand this